# How to get all opportunities owned by a salesforce account using their rest api?

Tags: rest-api, opportunity

I see there are ways to create, delete, read individual opportunities here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Opportunity

How to get all opportunities owned by a salesforce account using their rest api?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to go through [*How to Ask*](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [*edit your question*](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/237703/edit) to provide more details. It seems you want to query all opportunities associated to an account using REST API. If that's the case, please edit your question, in its current form, your question does not specify any issue.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need to fetch all Opportunities associated to an Account, you can just use **[Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm)** resource for this purpose.

In your case, your API call should look like:

```
https://yourinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/query?q=select+name+from+opportunity+where+accountid='<the account id>'
```